# Drag any label in the form using the mouse

Tags: vb.net

I need to drag any label that's on my form.

I am using this code, the problem is it only moves the 1 label `label1` 
I can copy paste several time and it works, but I am using a code to ad new labels to the form and that code does not see them.

How can I click and drag any label on the form?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim lbl As Label
    Dim Off As Point
    Private Sub obj1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles label1.MouseDown

        Off.X = MousePosition.X - sender.Left
        Off.Y = MousePosition.Y - sender.Top
    End Sub
    Private Sub obj1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles label1.MouseMove
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            sender.Left = MousePosition.X - Off.X
            sender.Top = MousePosition.Y - Off.Y
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: varocarbas answered you the first time...you need to connect the mouseXXX handlers for the new labels you create in code... show THAT code as it is more likely where a problem is

Comment: i now that he did and thanks to him so much but i am still confused and i dont want to ways his time i would appreciate if someone just copied the code and correct id and paste in here that would be great or even the line

Comment: ...and I would love it if someone would do my work for me too.  SHOW THE Code where you make new labels...thats where the problem almost surely is.  There is nothing to correct in varocarbas's code, we need to see how you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"i want to drag any label that is located in the form"

Instead of hard-wiring the handler with the "Handles xxx.yyy" clauses, wire them up at run-time in the Load() event of the Form:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Off As Point

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        WireLabels(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WireLabels(ByVal cont As Control)
        For Each ctl As Control In cont.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is Label Then
                AddHandler ctl.MouseDown, AddressOf obj1_MouseDown
                AddHandler ctl.MouseMove, AddressOf obj1_MouseMove
            ElseIf ctl.HasChildren Then
                WireLabels(ctl)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub obj1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        Off.X = MousePosition.X - sender.Left
        Off.Y = MousePosition.Y - sender.Top
    End Sub

    Private Sub obj1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            sender.Left = MousePosition.X - Off.X
            sender.Top = MousePosition.Y - Off.Y
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Obviously you'd use AddHandler for any Labels created at run-time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
Private Sub obj1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) 

    Off.X = MousePosition.X - sender.Left
    Off.Y = MousePosition.Y - sender.Top
End Sub
Private Sub obj1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) 
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        sender.Left = MousePosition.X - Off.X
        sender.Top = MousePosition.Y - Off.Y
    End If
End Sub
```

And in your form load have this:

```
AddHandler label1.MouseDown, Addressof obj1_MouseDown
AddHandler label1.MouseMove, Addressof obj1_MouseMove
```

And in your label creation code:

```
dim aLabel as label = new Label
AddHandler aLabel.MouseDown, Addressof obj1_MouseDown
AddHandler aLabel.MouseMove, Addressof obj1_MouseMove
...
```

you need to add the handlers to the objects after they are created, otherwise the form has no idea what to do with the events.

Comment: thank you everyone for your help i appreciate it it work perfectly Idle_Mind thank you